# webpack adding imports from lazy loaded entry to main entry

Tags: webpack, lazy-loading, code-splitting

I'm using webpack (v3.5.6) for building (bundling and compiling) a web application. In our main entry we (try to) lazy load another entry file, using this syntax:

`import(/* webpackChunkName: 'charts' */ './charts').then((module) => { /* do something with module */});`

With these entries defined:

```
entry: {
    'charts' : [`src/charts.ts`],
    'main' : [`src/main.ts`]
},
```

When webpack does its thing, it generates both entries but the main entry also contains the `charts` entry (plus all its imports).

In the webpack config, I have defined:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    names: ['charts'],
    minChunks: Infinity,
    async: true
})
```

Anyone got an idea why the main.js output also contains the charts bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this was not caused by webpack but by the way our Typescript config had set `module` to `commonjs` instead of `es2015` or `amd`.